# Generalizing forkIO to MonadIO

Tags: haskell

Is there any way to make `forkIO` classy?

```
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (MonadIO)
import Control.Concurrent (ThreadId)

-- | Is this possible?
forkIO :: MonadIO m => m () -> m ThreadId
forkIO = undefined
```

I'm trying to call it from within a function using a few `mtl` monad class constraints. I'm aware of `lifted-base` but I'd rather not have an extra `MonadBaseControl IO` constraint bubble up through my program. Solutions and/or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This would appear to require a function `MonadIO m => m () -> IO ()` which does not exist.

Comment: This can not be implemented for, e.g., `StateT s IO a` since that would require the state to be shared among multiple threads, which can not be achieved using the underlying type `s -> IO (s, a)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be done with `MonadIO`, but it can be done with `MonadUnliftIO`, see [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unliftio-0.2.7.0/docs/UnliftIO-Concurrent.html#v:forkIO).

Not everything that has a `MonadIO` instance also has a `MonadUnliftIO` instance, but depending on what you need this for this might be sufficient.